# Liferay custom services on iOS - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: liferay, xcode7

I am trying to consume custom web service from a liferay portlet but I am getting the not found architecture x86_64

I am using xcode 7.1.1 7B1005 running on El Capitan. Also using cocoapods and was able to call out of the box web service without any issues. It all started when I dragged the codes generated by liferay as part of my codes. There are no other compilation errors.

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
LRSession *session = [[LRSession alloc] initWithServer:@"http://localhost:8080"
                                        authentication:[[LRBasicAuthentication alloc]
                                                        initWithUsername:@"richard.g.reyes@accenture.com"
                                                        password:@"xxx"]];

[session onSuccess:^(id result) {
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
 } onFailure:^(NSError *e) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", e);
 }];
```

//    NSError *error;

```
LRGuestbookService_v62 *guestService = [[LRGuestbookService_v62 alloc] initWithSession:session];
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this:

What I am initially doing is drag the whole folder that the liferay generated into my project. For example, for Service/v_62/EntryService/EntryService.h, I dragged the whole service directory. Instead of that, I dragged the individual files and the error is resolved.

Hope this helps someone else.